# Filtrar por cierto valor un response - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Necesito filtrar ciertos datos que me devuelve un response. Actualmente, tendría que filtrar solo por contratos activos, sin embargo, me devuelve todos los contratos. Intente solucionar esto con un **.pipe()** pero no me sirvió. A continuación les muestro como intenté implementarlo.

```
findContracts() {
this.httpService.get('contracts', null)
  .pipe(
    map(contracts => contracts.filter(activeContracts => activeContracts.isActive == true))
  )
  .subscribe(contracts => {
    this.contractList = contracts.items;
    this.contracts = contracts.items;
    console.log(this.contractList);
  });
}
```

Sin embargo, intentado implementar esto, no me dió resultado. Espero puedan ayudarme! Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Tiene que ser `contracts.items.filter`

Comment: @Lobos Lo voy a estar probando!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas puedes probar esto.

```
findContracts() {
  this.httpService.get('contracts', null).subscribe(contracts => {
    const filterd = contracts.filter(contract =>  contract.isActive);
    this.contractList = filtered.items;
    this.contracts = filtered.items;
    console.log(this.contractList);
  });
}
```

Espero le ayude, saludos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muchas gracias Carles! Eso me sirvió. Una única modificación que tuve que realizar, es que al hacer el contracts.filter, tuve que agregarle el items en medio. Quedandomé de esta forma: ...contracts.items.filter...